# How to show different width on mobile vs desktop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following html

```
<div class="row why why-3">
   <div class="col-md-1 col-12">
       <div class="why-circle why-circle-3"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-11 why-right1 col-12">
      <h3 class="h3_headline">Meaningful Results</h3>
      <p>Test</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want two columns on desktop, but each column having the full width on mobile. I tried to do that above, with col-md-11 and col-12 but it's not working. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, rows are broken up into 12 columns.

This means if you want a single element to take up the entire row you would used something like

```
<div class="col-12">[Insert Content]</div>
```

If you want 2 columns you divide 12 by 2 and use that number in each 'col' instead like this

```
<div class="col-6">[Insert Content]</div>
<div class="col-6">[Insert Content]</div>
```

This pattern continues all the way down.

If any of this doesn't make sense, I recommend going back to the documentation.

[Bootstrap 4 Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) - This is how you get the layout you are looking for.

[Bootstrap 4 Responsive Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#responsive-classes) - This is how you make that layout specific to Mobile vs Desktop

[Bootstrap 4 Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) - This, I believe, explains how bootstrap decides which layout to show when, why, and on which types of devices (approximately).